# Build the testing repo before deploying to production in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testing, bdd

So I have a BDD testing project for a service and what I want is that as soon as I merge a branch into the master branch of that service then that BDD testing should be triggered first and if every test case passes then only it should allow to deploy the service to production.
The BDD is written in Cucumber-Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure this in a CI server such as Jenkins.

You can consider these steps, when setting up Jenkins, to achieve your use case:

- Use Git-hooks; This will trigger a Jenkins pipeline as soon you merge a branch into the master. Check this article for more info https://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/
- Then in Jenkins, run your BDD project. Here is a nice article, which explains how cucumber projects are setup and run in Jenkins:
  https://faun.pub/running-cucumber-tests-with-jenkins-a5a3a8df07eb
- When your cucumber project passes, then write a script in Jenkins to deploy into production (This would be a separate stage in Jenkins). Although I would recommend you to deploy this into a staging server or something like [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/), which would hold your release package and have a manual step to deploy into production.

Finally here is a detailed article that gives step by step explanation of how you could integrate NoCodeBDD with Jenkins. Though this article is for NoCodeBDD, you could copy these steps and apply them for any BDD project by changing some parts of the script.

https://blog.nocodebdd.com/integrate-nocodebdd-and-jenkins-to-run-bdd/

Comment: Can we do this on multibranch pipepline?